# Override aheadworks onestepcheckout extensions cc.js file

Tags: magento2, javascript, onestepcheckout

I have been looking a lot on how to override/extend js files, found a way using mixins but I cant figure it out how to do it correctly because it did not work for me. The file I need to override location:

`/vendor/aheadworks/module-onestepcheckout/view/frontend/web/js/model/render-postprocessor/float-label/converter/cc.js`

Whole code in `cc.js` file:

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/async',
        'underscore',
        'Aheadworks_OneStepCheckout/js/model/render-postprocessor/float-label/converter',
        'awOscFloatLabel',
        'mage/template',
        'mage/translate'
    ],
    function ($, _, Converter, floatLabel, mageTemplate, $t) {
        'use strict';

        var ccMethodCodes = [
            'authorizenet_directpost',
            'braintree',
            'cybersource',
            'eway'
        ];

        return _.extend({}, Converter, {

            /**
             * @inheritdoc
             */
            convertPaymentMethodInputs: function (methodItem) {
                var form = methodItem.find('form'),
                    methodCode = this._getPaymentMethodCode(methodItem),
                    expDateContainer = '#' + methodCode + '_cc_type_exp_div';

                if (form.length > 0) {
                    floatLabel({excludeFieldSelector: expDateContainer}, form);
                    if (this._isCCMethod(methodCode, methodItem)) {
                        $.async(
                            expDateContainer,
                            $.proxy(this._processExpirationDateInput, this)
                        );
                    }
                }
            },

            /**
             * Check if CC payment method
             *
             * @param {string} methodCode
             * @param {Object} methodItem
             * @returns {boolean}
             */
            _isCCMethod: function (methodCode, methodItem) {
                var form = methodItem.find('form');

                return _.indexOf(methodCode, ccMethodCodes) != -1
                    || form.is('#co-transparent-form, #co-transparent-form-braintree');
            },

            /**
             * Retrieve payment method code from method item element
             *
             * @param {Object} element
             * @returns {string}
             */
            _getPaymentMethodCode: function (element) {
                var input = element.find('input[name="payment[method]"]');

                return input.val();
            },

            /**
             * Process expiration date inputs
             *
             * @param {HTMLElement} container
             */
            _processExpirationDateInput: function (container) {
                var expMonth = $(container).find('[id$=_expiration]'),
                    expYear = $(container).find('[id$=_expiration_yr]'),
                    fields = $(container).find('.field');

                $(container).find('label').remove();
                $(container).find('div.no-label').removeClass('no-label');
                if ($(container).hasClass('required')) {
                    fields.addClass('required');
                }
                this._addLabel(expMonth, 'Expiration Month', 'Exp. Month');
                this._addLabel(expYear, 'Expiration Year', 'Exp. Year');

                _.each([expMonth, expYear], function (element) {
                    element.find('option').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).val() == '') {
                            $(this).html('');
                        }
                    })
                });

                fields.each(function () {
                    floatLabel({}, this);
                });
            },

            /**
             * Add label for input element
             *
             * @param {Object} element
             * @param {string} label
             * @param {string} shortLabel
             */
            _addLabel: function (element, label, shortLabel) {
                var labelTemplate = mageTemplate(this.labelTmplStr + this.shortLabelTmplStr),
                    target = element.closest('div.control');

                target.before(labelTemplate({
                    data: {
                        for: element.attr('id'),
                        label: $t(label),
                        shortLabel: $t(shortLabel)
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }
);
```

And what I want to do is extend `_processExpirationDateInput` function and change its labels, i.e., from

```
this._addLabel(expMonth, 'Expiration Month', 'Exp. Month');
```

to

```
this._addLabel(expMonth, 'Month', 'Exp. Month');
```

Can someone help me with advice? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only change the label then you can use [Magento 2 translation feature](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html) rather then overriding JS file. For example, If you have your custom module then you can create `en_US.csv` file under `i18n` directory and add the below content in `en_US.csv`

`app/code/YOUR_VENDOR/MODULE_NAME/i18n/en_US.csv`

`"Expiration Month","Month"`

If you have a custom theme then you can do it like this,

`app/design/frontend/YOUR_VENDOR/THEME_NAME/i18n/en_US.csv`

`"Expiration Month","Month"`

After adding `en_US.csv` clear your webshop cache.

`php bin/magento cache:clean`